# Jtable columns not horizontally scrollable in NetBeans GUI builder?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have the following JTable in my program which is placed inside a JScrollPane. I made it using the GUI builder provided by Netbeans.

[image]

The problem is some of the columns in the table is not visible and there is no horizontal scroll bar. I even set the horizontalScrollBarPolicy to ALWAYS and it didnt help. So how do I make the table scrollable?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **@Andrew Thompson** mentiond you should provide some code that addresses the problem. Without seeing your code it's hard to find out what's the problem. But a common workaround about that is as the following:

If you have correctly added your `JTable` to the `ViewPort` of a `JScrollPane` like this:

```
JTable jtable = new JTable();
//...
JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(jtable);
//sc.setViewportView(jtable); <- This way is correct too
//
getContentPane().add(sc);
```

Then the most probable problem is about the `AutoResizeMode` of your `JTable`. Try this:

```
jtable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said I switched off AUTO.RESIZE and now its scrollable. Since this is done in NetBeans GUI builder the codes are not editable, so I was just looking for which table property to change.